# How to use dual USB cameras using camera2 API on Android TV Box (Android 9)

Tags: android, android-camera2

I want to use two UVC cameras and show these images simultaneously on Android TV Box using camera2 API.

I'm using [VIM3](https://www.khadas.com/vim3) (Android 9 installed).

(Update 2020/03/05. I had tried with ODROID N2. But the same error occurred. )

This is the code to use two USB cameras:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "DualCameraSample";
    private Button mButton;
    private static final int REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION = 200;

    private CameraManager mCameraManager;
    private Integer mCameraNum;

    // Camera1
    private TextureView mTextureView1;
    private String mCameraId1 = null;
    private Size mPreviewSize1 = null;
    private CameraDevice mCameraDevice1 = null;
    private CaptureRequest.Builder mPreviewBuilder1 = null;
    private CameraCaptureSession mCaptureSession1 = null;

    private UsbManager mUsbManager;

    private TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener mSurfaceTextureListner1 = new TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener() {

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureUpdated(SurfaceTexture surface) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onSurfaceTextureUpdated()");
        }

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged()");
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(SurfaceTexture surface) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onSurfaceTextureDestroyed()");
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onSurfaceTextureAvailable()");
            try {
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,
                        Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                        && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,
                        Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                            new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                            REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION);
                    return;
                }
                mCameraManager.openCamera(mCameraId1, mStateCallback1, null);
            } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    };

    private CameraDevice.StateCallback mStateCallback1 = new CameraDevice.StateCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onOpened(CameraDevice camera) {
            Log.i(TAG, "mStateCallback1 onOpened");
            mCameraDevice1 = camera;
            Log.w(TAG, "mCameraId1: " + mCameraDevice1.getId());

            SurfaceTexture texture = mTextureView1.getSurfaceTexture();
            if (texture == null) {
                Log.e(TAG, "texture is null");
                return;
            }

            texture.setDefaultBufferSize(mPreviewSize1.getWidth(), mPreviewSize1.getHeight());
            Surface surface = new Surface(texture);

            try {
                mPreviewBuilder1 = mCameraDevice1.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW);
            } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            mPreviewBuilder1.addTarget(surface);

            try {
                mCameraDevice1.createCaptureSession(Arrays.asList(surface), mPreviewStateCallback1, null);
            } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                mCameraDevice1.close();
                mCameraDevice1 = null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(CameraDevice camera, int error) {
            Log.e(TAG, String.format("mStateCallback1 onError: %d",  error));
            Log.e(TAG, "mStateCallback1 onError: " + camera.getId());
            mCameraDevice1.close();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDisconnected(CameraDevice camera) {
            Log.e(TAG, "mStateCallback1 onDisconnected");
        }
    };

    private CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback mPreviewStateCallback1 = new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onConfigured(CameraCaptureSession session) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onConfigured");
            mCaptureSession1 = session;

            mPreviewBuilder1.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_MODE_AUTO);

            HandlerThread backgroundThread = new HandlerThread("CameraPreview");
            backgroundThread.start();
            Handler backgroundHandler = new Handler(backgroundThread.getLooper());

            try {
                mCaptureSession1.setRepeatingRequest(mPreviewBuilder1.build(), null, backgroundHandler);
            } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onConfigureFailed(CameraCaptureSession session) {
            Log.e(TAG, "CameraCaptureSession Configure failed");
        }
    };

    // Camera2
    private TextureView mTextureView2;
    private String mCameraId2 = null;
    private Size mPreviewSize2 = null;
    private CameraDevice mCameraDevice2 = null;
    private CaptureRequest.Builder mPreviewBuilder2 = null;
    private CameraCaptureSession mCaptureSession2 = null;

    private TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener mSurfaceTextureListner2 = new TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener() {

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureUpdated(SurfaceTexture surface) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onSurfaceTextureUpdated()");
        }

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged()");
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(SurfaceTexture surface) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onSurfaceTextureDestroyed()");
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onSurfaceTextureAvailable()");
            try {
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,
                        Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                        && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,
                        Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                            new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                            REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION);
                    return;
                }
                mCameraManager.openCamera(mCameraId2, mStateCallback2, null);
            } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    };

    private CameraDevice.StateCallback mStateCallback2 = new CameraDevice.StateCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onOpened(CameraDevice camera) {
            Log.i(TAG, "mStateCallback2 onOpened");
            mCameraDevice2 = camera;
            Log.w(TAG, "mCameraId2: " + mCameraDevice2.getId());

            SurfaceTexture texture = mTextureView2.getSurfaceTexture();
            if (texture == null) {
                Log.e(TAG, "texture is null");
                return;
            }

            texture.setDefaultBufferSize(mPreviewSize2.getWidth(), mPreviewSize2.getHeight());
            Surface surface = new Surface(texture);

            try {
                mPreviewBuilder2 = mCameraDevice2.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW);
            } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            mPreviewBuilder2.addTarget(surface);

            try {
                mCameraDevice2.createCaptureSession(Arrays.asList(surface), mPreviewStateCallback2, null);
            } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(CameraDevice camera, int error) {
            Log.e(TAG, String.format("mStateCallback2 onError: %d",  error));
            Log.e(TAG, "mStateCallback2 onError: " + camera.getId());
            mCameraDevice2.close();
            mCameraDevice2 = null;
        }

        @Override
        public void onDisconnected(CameraDevice camera) {
            Log.e(TAG, "mStateCallback2 onDisconnected");
        }
    };

    private CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback mPreviewStateCallback2 = new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onConfigured(CameraCaptureSession session) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onConfigured");
            mCaptureSession2 = session;

            mPreviewBuilder2.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_MODE_AUTO);

            HandlerThread backgroundThread = new HandlerThread("CameraPreview");
            backgroundThread.start();
            Handler backgroundHandler = new Handler(backgroundThread.getLooper());

            try {
                mCaptureSession2.setRepeatingRequest(mPreviewBuilder2.build(), null, backgroundHandler);
            } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onConfigureFailed(CameraCaptureSession session) {
            Log.e(TAG, "CameraCaptureSession Configure failed");
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        usbDeviceList();
        getCameraIDs();

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION);
            return;
        }

        if (mCameraId1 != null) {
            mTextureView1 = (TextureView) findViewById(R.id.cameraTextureView1);
            mTextureView1.setSurfaceTextureListener(mSurfaceTextureListner1);
        }
        if (mCameraId2 != null) {
            mTextureView2 = (TextureView) findViewById(R.id.cameraTextureView2);
            mTextureView2.setSurfaceTextureListener(mSurfaceTextureListner2);
        }
    }

    private void getCameraIDs () {
        Log.d(TAG, "func getCameraIDs");
        // Init  Manager
        mCameraManager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
        try {

            //Get Camera  List
            String[] CameraIdList = mCameraManager.getCameraIdList();
            mCameraNum = CameraIdList.length;
            Log.d(TAG, "CameraId List : " + Arrays.toString(CameraIdList));

            // Set CameraIDs
            int i = 0;
            for(String cameraId: CameraIdList) {
                CameraCharacteristics characteristics = mCameraManager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraId);
                StreamConfigurationMap map = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP);

                // Set Camera Id
                if (i == 0) {
                    mCameraId1 = cameraId;
                    Log.d(TAG, "mCameraId1 : " + mCameraId1);
                    mPreviewSize1 = map.getOutputSizes(SurfaceTexture.class)[0];
                } else {
                    mCameraId2 = cameraId;
                    Log.d(TAG, "mCameraId2 : " + mCameraId2);
                    mPreviewSize2 = map.getOutputSizes(SurfaceTexture.class)[0];
                }
                i++;
            }
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void usbDeviceList() {
        mUsbManager = (UsbManager)getSystemService(USB_SERVICE);
        HashMap<String, UsbDevice> deviceList = mUsbManager.getDeviceList();

        if (deviceList == null || deviceList.isEmpty()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "CameraId : No USB Device");
        } else {
            for (String name : deviceList.keySet()) {
                Log.d(TAG, String.format("[CameraId] name: %s, VendorId: %d, getProductName: %s, getProductId: %d",
                        name,
                        deviceList.get(name).getVendorId(),
                        deviceList.get(name).getProductName(),
                        deviceList.get(name).getProductId()));
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION) {
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
                // close the app
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Sorry!!!, you can't use this app without granting permission", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                finish();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, it crashes when opening the second camera precess.
The errors are as follows:

```
2020-02-15 22:26:28.938 9792-9792/? E/DualCameraSample: mStateCallback2 onError: 4
2020-02-15 22:26:28.938 9792-9792/? E/DualCameraSample: mStateCallback2 onError: 1
2020-02-15 22:26:28.940 9792-9792/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: test.example.dualcamerasample, PID: 9792
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.hardware.camera2.CameraDevice.close()' on a null object reference
        at test.example.dualcamerasample.MainActivity$5.onError(MainActivity.java:254)
        at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl$8.run(CameraDeviceImpl.java:348)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

USBManager recognizes two USB cameras,

```
2020-02-15 22:19:53.349 9657-9657/test.example.dualcamerasample D/DualCameraSample: [CameraId] name: /dev/bus/usb/001/012, VendorId: 1133, getProductName: null, getProductId: 2085
2020-02-15 22:19:53.349 9657-9657/test.example.dualcamerasample D/DualCameraSample: [CameraId] name: /dev/bus/usb/001/010, VendorId: 1443, getProductName: USB 2.0 Camera, getProductId: 37424
```

Also, CameraManager has confirmed that two of the camera.

I certainly set mCameraId1 to 0 and mCameraId2 to 1.

```
2020-02-15 22:19:53.352 9657-9657/test.example.dualcamerasample D/DualCameraSample: CameraId List : [0, 1]
2020-02-15 22:19:53.361 9657-9657/test.example.dualcamerasample D/DualCameraSample: mCameraId1 : 0
2020-02-15 22:19:53.367 9657-9657/test.example.dualcamerasample D/DualCameraSample: mCameraId2 : 1
```

Once I commented out the following code in onCreate and run with just one camera, it worked.

However, even if I comment out either mTextureView1 or mTextureView2, the first camera image is displayed on TextureView.

```
mTextureView1.setSurfaceTextureListener(mSurfaceTextureListner1);
```

or

```
mTextureView2.setSurfaceTextureListener(mSurfaceTextureListner2);
```

How to use dual USB cameras using camera2 API on Android 9?

I have seen some 3rd party UVC libraries for Android, but I don't use them and want to use native Android code.

Comment: hello friend, I have same problem, do you have solution for this case?